# Как правильно написать realloc() для массива структур?

Tags: c, структуры, память

Имеется структура - `discipliny` с множеством полей и массивом `disciplina[n]`. Динамически память распределяю в таком виде

```
disciplina = (discipliny*)malloc(sizeof(*disciplina))*n;
```

Необходимо, чтобы при чтении из файла новых элементов память для массива автоматически расширялась. Пробовал написать в различных вариациях написать

```
disciplina = realloc(disciplina, sizeof(*disciplina)*i);
```

но все ошибки пишет, помогите правильно написать эту функцию.

Полный код структуры:

`struct discipliny {char nazvanie[20], otchet[6]; int vse_chasy; }`

Объявление в мейне:

```
discipliny *disciplina;
disciplina = (discipliny*)malloc(sizeof(disciplina)*n);
```

Функция чтения из файла:

`while(fscanf(file, "%d\n")==NULL)`
    {

```
            fscanf(file,"%s", disciplina[i].nazvanie);
            fscanf(file," %d\n", &(disciplina[i].vse_chasy));
            i++;
            disciplina = realloc(disciplina, sizeof(disciplina)*i);
            *n=i;
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: Какие ошибки? Похоже, у Вас первоначальное распределение с ошибкой:

       (discipliny*)malloc(sizeof(*disciplina)*n)

вместо

       (discipliny*)malloc(sizeof(disciplina)*n)

А вообще, по моему мнению, за выражения типа

       но все ошибки пишет,

следует наказывать. Вам лень написать (copy/paste), что за ошибки. Чем иным, если не неуважением к читающими Ваш вопрос можно считать такое поведение?

Comment: Просто не хотел сильно загружать пользователем кодом и узнать как правильно написать эту функцию...
В изначальном виде ошибки только к строке с realloc

  =: невозможно преобразовать "void *" в "discipliny *"
  Для преобразования "void*" к указателю на тип, не являющемуся "void", требуется явное приведение

Поменял на `(discipliny*)malloc(sizeof(disciplina)*n)`, те же ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {char nazvanie[20], otchet[6]; int vse_chasy; } discipliny ;
int main() {
    int i, n=1;
    FILE    *file;
    file = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    discipliny *disciplina;
    disciplina = (discipliny*)malloc(sizeof(discipliny)*n);
    i=0;
    while(!feof(file)) {
            fscanf(file,"%19s", disciplina[i].nazvanie);
            fscanf(file," %d\n", &(disciplina[i].vse_chasy));
            i++;
            disciplina = realloc(disciplina, sizeof(discipliny)*(i+1));
            n=i;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Вся соль была в том, что чтение выполнялось в функции 
`void read(discipliny *disciplina, int *n)`
которая объявляется в мейне 
`read(disciplina, &n);`
В этом случае и выдает ошибку преобразования "void " в "discipliny ". Если все делать в мейне, как Вы предложили, то все нормально.
Спасибо за ответ, все в мейн закинул.

Comment: @reger: невозможно, чтобы код работал в main и не работал в другой функции, если только вы не делаете какую-то дикую ошибку.

Comment: @VladD Если Вы сравните мой текст и текст @reger, то обнаружите ряд отличий. Ну то, что некоторые вещи на C просто не транслируются (пришлось добавить typedef) -- это ладно. C, C++ -- терпимо. Но вот `sizeof(disciplina)` -- это уже явная ошибка. Переменная `i`, которая для `realloc` д.б. на единицу больше. Может ещё что упустил.

Comment: @reger, закинуть в main, поскольку в функции не компилится, это плохое решение.

У Вас какая-то очень простая ошибка, связанная с тем, что имя переменной и типа очень похожи.

Вообще, я почти всегда пишу в sizeof() имя-переменной (в malloc/realloc \*имя-указателя), а не тип.

Кстати, увеличивать размер массива на 1 элемент на каждой итерации - это не самая хорошая идея. Лучше сразу выделить разумное количество памяти, например, страницу (или несколько) и при ее исчерпании добавить еще страницу и т.д., а в конце уже сделать realloc, уменьшающий размер массива до реальной величины.

Comment: @avp В принципе -- правильно, на в данном конкретном случае @reger мог бы ошибки и не заметить. А вот имя переменной/имя класса-структуры (C++) -- это да.

А указание *var в sizeof вместо типа -- уже дело личных предпочтений и дискутабельно.

Comment: Все таки вернулся к своему исходному варианту, ошибка была в том, что перед realloc надо было добавить (discipliny*) и как посоветовал @avp, в saizeof использовать переменную, то есть в моем сходном варианте изменил на `disciplina = (discipliny*)realloc(disciplina, sizeof(disciplina)*i);` и все заработало. Всем большое спасибо.

Comment: Первоначальный вариант -- это тот, что видно в вопросе?

     struct discipliny {char nazvanie[20], otchet[6]; int vse_chasy; }
     discipliny *disciplina;

     fscanf(file," %d\n", &(disciplina[i].vse_chasy));
     i++;

и дальше

     disciplina = (discipliny*)realloc(disciplina, sizeof(disciplina)*i);

Если так, то тут ошибки не исправлены. А то, что программа выполняется без ругани -- ну бывает. Лучше бы ругалась, поскольку отказ программы у заказчика -- ситуация куда менее приятная.

Добавьте исправленный код в вопрос, если не сложно.

Comment: Под первоначальным имел ввиду исходный, который в описании. Там я поменял только `disciplina = realloc(disciplina, sizeof(disciplina)*i);` на `disciplina = (discipliny*)realloc(disciplina, sizeof(disciplina)*i);`
Ошибки преобразования "void " в "discipliny " больше нету. В целом полет нормальный.

Comment: @reger Хотелось бы видеть целиком. Чему равно `i`? Чему равно `sizeof(disciplina)`?